# Preg_match remove text that creates a pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I currently have the code

```
$sPattern = "/<\/td><td>\(Shotgun\)(.*?)<\/td><td>/";
preg_match_all($sPattern,$homepage,$aMatch);
```

It works fine extracting multiple lines from a particular website but when it extracts them and echos them in an array it brings the `</td><td>` and `</td><td>` with it.

Is it possible to stop it from bringing those tags in the pattern with them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just echo what you're capturing in the capturing group instead of the whole match:

```
foreach( $aMatch[1] as $match)
    echo $match;
```

If you want "(Shotgun)" in the output as well, modify your regex to capture it:

```
$sPattern = "/<\/td><td>(\(Shotgun\).*?)<\/td><td>/";
```

Then you can use the same code to print it out above.

Comment: Did not realize I was echoing the entire array string, I feel like an idiot.  Thank you.

Comment: @Tim - Not a problem, glad I could help. If my post answered your question, please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)